# Conservative FV Immersed boundary method for compressible flow

Tags: finite-volume

Is there a conservative FV second-order (or first-order) accurate immersed boundary method for compressible flow including moving boundaries (in the literature)?

- By compressible flow I mean the Navier-Stokes eqts. for an ideal gas.
- Most of the results I am able to find deal exclusively with incompressible flows.
- It would be nice if the publication describes the method in enough detail that one can reproduce their results.

Comment: My limited knowledge on the subject would suggest looking into Zhilin Li's work on the subject.  He may at the very least be able to direct you towards literature that is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several research groups that are working on IBMs for compressible flow. A quick Google search leads to the following papers...

http://www.me.jhu.edu/fsag/Publications/Papers/AShapecompressibleJCP.pdf
http://multiscalemodeling.colorado.edu/liu/publications/Liu_JCP_2007.pdf
http://ctr.stanford.edu/ResBriefs05/detullio.pdf
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045793006000065
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/fld.3872/abstract
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10618562.2013.791391#.UvtnHnn0jRo
http://dutw1479.wbmt.tudelft.nl/~wim/academy/presentations/c1/pres_sanderse.pdf

Most of them seem to give enough detail so you can get started with your own implementation. Few people will be ready to give so much detail that you can write your own solver from scratch. When writing such codes, the devil is in the detail...